# How to delete uicollectionviewcell core data item in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My code below using the itemName.remove(at: sender.tag) deletes an item from the collectionviewcell. However when the class is recalled it reappears so it is not delete forever. The code starting at and below let noteEntity = Item() is causing runtime errors. I just want to remove the compile errors because this code should do what I need it to.

```
Var itemName : [Item] = []
 @objc func elete(_ sender:UIButton){
    itemName.remove(at: sender.tag)



   let noteEntity = "itemName" //Entity Name

      let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

      let note = itemName[indexPath.row]


         managedContext.delete(note)

         do {
             try managedContext.save()
         } catch let error as NSError {
             print("Error While Deleting Note: \(error.userInfo)")
         }



     //Code to Fetch New Data From The DB and Reload Table.
     let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: noteEntity)

     do {
         notes = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Note]
     } catch let error as NSError {
         print("Error While Fetching Data From DB: \(error.userInfo)")
     }
     collectionView.reloadData()
}}
```

[image]

Comment: indexPath is only for the collectionView method

Comment: I just added     Var itemName : [Item] = [] in my code. Item is the name of the core data table.

Comment: `let note = itemName[sender.tag]`